# Creating unique sessions per user on Webforms ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

We are currently developing a simple system on ASP.net which are going to be used by users simultaneously. What I want to happen is to get each users' `Name` (or any other useful info) from a SQL table every time they log in to the system and use this data all throughout (Note: this data should be unique per user).

Now my question is, what is the proper approach on this kind of scenario to give unique variable/session per user? And what if I want to make this variable a global one?

Sample Scenario: A doctor logs in to the system and the code behind gets his name from the table and prompts the data on the homepage - "Welcome Doctor John!" (assuming his name is doctor John. Another user logs in to the system, gets his name and prompts respectively, now the conflict arises if the first user - John, refreshes the page and this is the conflict that I want to avoid.

Any article that I could read on with regards the matter? Any help would be much appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am still a beginner when it comes to ASP.net so my apologies for such simple question.

Comment: This comes out of the box with the "Session" property of the page. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx) is where you will keep this information. It will be unique for each user. Read more about it at: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)

Just remember, that Sessions are maintained on Server for each user. They are costly. So if you keep too much data in your session then you may end up claiming more resources on the server.

Consider the following example where you retrieve your `UserInfo` in an object from Database.

```
UserInfo userInfo = GetUserInfoFromDB();
```

To Store information in Session:

```
//once user is authenticated
//store session
Session["UserInfo"] = userInfo;
```

To Retrieve information:

```
UserInfo currentUserInfo = Session["UserInfo"] as UserInfo;
if(currentUserInfo != null)
{
    //info found
    // assign lable Text currentUserInfo.UserName etc
}
```

You may see: [Exploring Session in ASP.NET - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

Comment: Thank you! Chose this answer due to brief and concise answer.

Comment: How much is "too much data" data that can be stored in the session variable?

Comment: @user1426542, that depends on your Server configuration, available memory, average number of users at any particular time. This is something very subjective, Just keep minimal possible data and see if your server can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Builtin Session Management. It is unique to the user. 
The Session Management stores, by default, a cookie at the users browser
to identifiy them. Only a Session Id is stored at the users browser and the other information, in your case the name, is stored on the server. You can define a Session Database for example if you have multiple webservers and want a single point to store the data.

If you have a single webserver it is very easy to use out of the box.

Set a Session variable.

```
Session["UserName"] = yourUsernameVariable;
```

Retrieve a Session variable.

```
var userName = Session["UserName"];
```

Here are some tutorials.

- [A Beginner's Tutorial on ASP.NET State Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management)
- [Exploring Session in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)
- [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)