# c# Multiple Sql results and session values

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, session

I have an SQL DB which is filled with users (id,First_Name,Surname,Email_Account,etc..).
Im Searching the DataBase based on Name and i show links , If that link is clicked then it redirects you to the users page.

My problem is when i try to pass the session variables, so when the link gets clicked then pageload is loading from the Session variables.

So when i have multiple search results , with the way i do it the last result session variables pass.

Here's the code! :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DisplayingImages
{
    public partial class WebForm7 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MPAPASYMEON;Server=mpapasymeon;Database=LOGIN;Initial Catalog=LOGIN; User ID=nikolaossts; Password=aaa;Connect Timeout=240");
        string PID2;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable PassRecord = new DataTable();
            String str = "select First_Name,Email_Account,Surname,id from ID where (First_Name like '%'+ @search +'%' ) OR (Surname like '%'+ @search +'%') OR (Email_Account like '%'+ @search +'%')";
            SqlCommand Srch = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            Srch.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                con.Open();
                Srch.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = Srch;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dt);

                DataTable Results = new DataTable;
                PID =(int)( Session["id"]);

                int SaveTheFirst = PID;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {                    
                    PID2 = dr["id"].ToString();

                    if (PID.ToString() != PID2 )
                    {                     
                        var field = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageView.aspx?Email=" +                     dr["id"].ToString()) + "'>" + (dr["First_Name"] + "").ToString() + "</a>";

                        Session["SurnameView"] = dr["Surname"];
                        string check1 = dr["Surname"].ToString();
                        Session["idView"] = dr["id"];
                        string check2 = dr["id"].ToString();
                        Session["EmailView"] = dr["Email_Account"];
                        string check3 = dr["Email_Account"].ToString();

                        Response.Write(field);

                        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                        Response.Write("<br/>");
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                string display = " Not Valid Search Criteria!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
            }
        }

        public string SN { get; set; }
        public string PS { get; set; }
        public string EM { get; set; }
        public int PID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put an identifier to each session? Like for instance, the ID of your user or something else that you can map to? That way you will be able to associate each session, with a user - after creating the sessions. Otherwise, if you don't use a unique identifier that does not match your business logic, you would not be able to associate the session...

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                PID2 = dr["id"].ToString();
                if (PID.ToString() != PID2 )
                {

                    var field = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageView.aspx?Email=" +                     dr["id"].ToString()) + "'>" + (dr["First_Name"] + "").ToString() + "</a>";

                    Session["SurnameView_" + PID2 ] = dr["Surname"];
                    string check1 = dr["Surname"].ToString();
                    Session["idView_" + PID2] = dr["id"];
                    string check2 = dr["id"].ToString();
                    Session["EmailView_" + PID2] = dr["Email_Account"];
                    string check3 = dr["Email_Account"].ToString();



                    Response.Write(field);

                    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                    Response.Write("<br/>");
                }
            }
```

Have a look at these links to get a better idea of how to create unique sessions per user

- [Creating unique sessions per user on Webforms ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166288/creating-unique-sessions-per-user-on-webforms-asp-net)
- [how safe is it to use session variables - asp.net / c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451543/how-safe-is-it-to-use-session-variables-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: so what you tell me, is that everywhere in my program, i should put Session["XXXX"+ID], right!?

Comment: The controlling of sessions, such as this, would ideally be called through a public static class which handles creation, and deletion of sessions. Calling for example SessionUtilities.CreateSession(Session["XXXX"+ID]). Yes, this would create sessions per user.

Comment: hmm i see can you redirect me somewhere so i can read or post some example code? thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

One way to save it in the session

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{

    PID2 = dr["id"].ToString();
    if (PID.ToString() != PID2 )
    {
        counter+=1;
        //do stuff
        Session["Email_" + counter] = dr["Surname"];
    }
}
```

But in this case you should add the counter to the url parameters.

```
var field = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/PageView.aspx?Email=" +  dr["id"].ToString()) + "&counter=" + counter "'>" + (dr["First_Name"] + "").ToString() + "</a>";
```

In this case when you open the page you will know which session parameter is needed.

The other way is just to write all of your values in the Url and take them after that.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a `HiddenField` to store the data in which you want to pass. `Session` is not really reliable for multiple instances

Comment: Can you elaborate on the comment "Session is not really reliable for multiple instances".